# Нахождение главного потока

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Ситуация такая. Есть некое приложение. У приложения много потоков, в одном из потоков висит окно приложения с известным названием класса и window name. Как нам его найти? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [`FindWindowEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
HWND WINAPI FindWindowEx(
  __in_opt  HWND hwndParent,
  __in_opt  HWND hwndChildAfter,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpszClass,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpszWindow
);
```

**UPD:** Найти поток, в котором было создано то или иное окно, можно используя метод [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
DWORD WINAPI GetWindowThreadProcessId(
  __in       HWND hWnd,
  __out_opt  LPDWORD lpdwProcessId
);
```

Comment: Вы меня не правильно поняли видимо) Функция, которую вы привели, находит элементы. Мне нужно найти главный поток (thread) приложения

Comment: Точно, как я забыл про неё( спасибо большое :)